# LISP break a function execution

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, break

How can I break a function execution in LISP if I get a certain value?

For example, I have a main function like this:

```
(defun recognize-a (arg input)
    (if (equal (recognize-b arg input) '())
        T
      NIL
      ))
```

I want to break the function `recognize-b` in case the input is an empty list, without passing any values to the main function:

```
(defun recognize-b (fa input)
  (if (equal input '())
      <<<WANTED BREAK>>>
     (<Else branch>)))
```

Comment: Do you mean "break" as in calling [`BREAK`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_break.htm)?

Comment: Yes, but i need something that let the main function fails if a certain condition is verified in the sub-function recognize-b

Comment: Can you clarify the question a little. Do you want a break point that invokes the debugger as a development tool, or do you just want the function to signal an error that another function will handle?

Comment: Without the break i mean to use, if `recognize-b` gets `( ) `  as input, `recognize-a` would return T. I need a break in `recognize-b` that completely broke up all the   execution in case of empty input. Sorry for the not so clear argumentation.

Comment: Just looking at the code it's clear that you can solve this by just returning `nil` since the `if ` is in tail position. Why isn't that an option?

Comment: Because if i return `nil` in the `if` clause, the main function `recognize-a` reading `nil` will return T.

Comment: So return `t` then.. It will return `nil`.. Basically those are the two outcomes of the outer function and inserted of the `if` just the `(not predicate) ` will do the same.

Comment: yes, seems the best solution, ty.

Comment: `(if (equal ...) t nil)` is just `(equal ...)`.

Comment: @RainerJoswig or `(not (recognize-b arg input))` :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ERROR`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_error.htm) to signal an error from `RECOGNIZE-B` when `INPUT` is empty.

```
(defun recognize-b (arg input)
  (when (emptyp input)
    (error "INPUT is empty!"))
  ;; Do whatever the function normally does...
  :return-value-from-b)
```

I'll just return `:RETURN-VALUE-FROM-B` since I don't know what the function is supposed to do. You could define an error type to signal, but by default `ERROR` will signal a `SIMPLE-ERROR`.

To handle the error in `RECOGNIZE-A`, you can use [`HANDLER-CASE`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_hand_1.htm#handler-case).

```
(defun recognize-a (arg input)
  (handler-case (recognize-b arg input)
    (simple-error () t)))
```

This simply returns the value from `RECOGNIZE-B` if there was no error, or `T` if there was.

```
(recognize-a 10 '(1 2)) ;=> :RETURN-VALUE-FROM-B
(recognize-a 10 '()) ;=> T
```

There is a good introduction to the condition system in the book [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/), [Chapter 19. Beyond Exception Handling: Conditions and Restarts](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/beyond-exception-handling-conditions-and-restarts.html).